# Delaunay triangulation is not correctly constructed when plotting the intersection area of two inequalities

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, triangulation

In the code that uses the NumPy, Matplotlib, SymPy, and SciPy libraries, there is a function called plot_inequalities which is intended to plot the intersection area of two inequalities using Delaunay triangulation. However, when running the code, the Delaunay triangulation is not constructed correctly.Here is code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import *
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

def plot_inequalities(inequality1, inequality2, x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max):
x, y = symbols('x y')
try:
inequality1_expr = sympify(inequality1)
inequality2_expr = sympify(inequality2)
except:
    print("Error: Incorrect inequality format.")
    return

try:
    F1 = lambdify((x, y), inequality1_expr, 'numpy')
    F2 = lambdify((x, y), inequality2_expr, 'numpy')
except:
    print("Error: Failed to compile inequalities.")
    return

# Create grid of x and y values
x_vals = np.concatenate(([0], np.linspace(x_min, x_max, 400)))
y_vals = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, 400)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x_vals, y_vals)
# Check inequalities at each grid point
inequality1_result = F1(X, Y)
inequality2_result = F2(X, Y)

# Find intersection points of the inequalities
intersection_points = []
for i in range(len(x_vals)):
    for j in range(len(y_vals)):
        if inequality1_result[j, i] < 0 and inequality2_result[j, i] > 0:
            intersection_points.append([x_vals[i], y_vals[j]])

intersection_points = np.array(intersection_points)

# Delaunay triangulation of intersection points
if len(intersection_points) >= 3:
    tri = Delaunay(intersection_points[:, :2])

    # Plot the graph
    plt.triplot(intersection_points[:, 0], intersection_points[:, 1], tri.simplices.copy(), color='black')

# Display the graph
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.grid(False)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.xlim(x_min, x_max)
plt.ylim(y_min, y_max)
plt.show()
print("Enter the lower inequality in the format 'F(x, y) > 0':")
inequality1 = input()
print("Enter the upper inequality in the format 'F(x, y) < 0':")
inequality2 = input()
print("Enter the x interval boundaries in the format 'x_min, x_max':")
x_min, x_max = map(float, input().split(','))
print("Enter the y interval boundaries in the format 'y_min, y_max':")
y_min, y_max = map(float, input().split(','))

plot_inequalities(inequality1, inequality2, x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max)
```

example area: y-x>0 and y-x**2<0

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the `plot_inequalities` function is that the `intersection_points` array is not being properly filtered to remove duplicate points. When the `intersection_points` array contains duplicate points, the Delaunay triangulation cannot be constructed correctly. To fix this issue, you can add a check to remove duplicate points from the `intersection_points` array before constructing the Delaunay triangulation.

Here's the updated code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import *
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection

def plot_inequalities(inequality1, inequality2, x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max):
    x, y = symbols('x y')
    try:
        inequality1_expr = sympify(inequality1)
        inequality2_expr = sympify(inequality2)
    except:
        print("Error: Incorrect inequality format.")
        return

    try:
        F1 = lambdify((x, y), inequality1_expr, 'numpy')
        F2 = lambdify((x, y), inequality2_expr, 'numpy')
    except:
        print("Error: Failed to compile inequalities.")
        return

    # Create grid of x and y values
    x_vals, y_vals = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(x_min, x_max, 150), np.linspace(y_min, y_max, 400))
    
    # Check inequalities on grid points
    indices = np.where((F1(x_vals, y_vals) < 0) & (F2(x_vals, y_vals) > 0))
    intersection_points = np.column_stack((x_vals[indices], y_vals[indices]))

    # Remove any duplicate points
    intersection_points = np.unique(intersection_points, axis=0)

    # Delaunay triangulation of intersection points
    if len(intersection_points) >= 3:
        tri = Delaunay(intersection_points)

        # Plot the graph
        polys = PolyCollection(intersection_points[tri.simplices], facecolors='none', edgecolors='black')
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.add_collection(polys)
        ax.autoscale()
        ax.margins(0.1)
        ax.set_xlabel('x')
        ax.set_ylabel('y')
        ax.set_aspect('equal')
        plt.show()

print("Enter the lower inequality in the format 'F(x, y) > 0':")
inequality1 = "y - x "
print("Enter the upper inequality in the format 'F(x, y) < 0':")
inequality2 = "y - x**2 "
print("Enter the x interval boundaries in the format 'x_min, x_max':")
x_min, x_max = map(float, "0,4".split(','))
print("Enter the y interval boundaries in the format 'y_min, y_max':")
y_min, y_max = map(float, "0,4".split(','))

plot_inequalities(inequality1, inequality2, x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max)
```

With this modification, the `intersection_points` array is first converted to a numpy array and then filtered using the `unique` function to remove any duplicate points. The resulting `intersection_points` array is then used to construct the Delaunay triangulation and plot the intersection area of the two inequalities.

**P.S.** I have hard coded the inequality in the code. You can vary the number of `x_vals` and `y_vals` by changing the number of points in `np.linspace(x_min, x_max, 150)`  and `np.linspace(y_min, y_max, 400)` to see triangulations.

[image: delaunay-triangulation image]

Comment: this did not help, the area is still not triangulated

Comment: Please check the output. I have further optimized the code to remove loops.

Comment: Thanks, but,why is this not done for other straight lines, for example y-1>0 and y-4<0 ?

Comment: The area between these two inequality is a strip between y=1 and y=4. These two lines dont intersect and hence no points for triangulation to work.

Comment: Thanks...Why does this code, despite entering interval boundaries, result in an x-axis segment from 0 to 1 and a y-axis segment from 0 to 1, and how can these boundaries be changed?

Comment: The boundaries depend on the intersection point of equations. The interval we enter is for the overall shape of the graph obtained.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was helpful!When constructing regions bounded by other inequalities, the region is constructed, but there is no Delaunay triangulation. Don't know why that is?